# Switching different template part in wordpress on window-resize

Tags: jquery, wordpress, if-statement, switch-statement, responsive-design

In my wordpress template I have added my template part in header.php using wordpress function.

```
<?php get_template_part('desktop'); ?>
```

I want to add diffrent template part for different screen sizes as well as for mobile screens . How to grab the window width automatically according to device resolution or on window re-size? And How to get those value as condition to switch template part? I have my different template named 
`ipad-portrait.php, ipad-landscape.php and tinymobile.php.`

Comment: can't determine screen size at server... would have to load using AJAX and have javascript determine the paramters

Comment: How can we catch the screen width of device or screen width on window-resize using javascript?

Comment: use `resize()` handler... see example that gets width in the docs  http://api.jquery.com/resize/

Answer (score 0):

Using Jquery I can catch the width of window on re-size :

My Jquery:

```
<script type=text/javascript>
  $(window).resize(function() {
    var _my_window = $(window).width();
      alert(_my_window);
   }); 
</script>
```

I think this is not easy to pass this jquery variable directly to store it as a php variable .